# convert fitz.get_text coordination into image pixels

Tags: python

I have a program that I wanted to highlight the image coordination of each text.
I used fitz.get_text('block') and I got a rectangle of coordination of block.
But, when I use coordination to highlight images, coordination was not ok.

how can I convert fitz.get_text('block') into pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I used pdf2image (using poppler) and converted the pdf into image.
I used fitz.get_text('dict') to find out the width and height of pdf and calculated the ratio of pdf blocks by image.
The solution was so easy. just multiply width to 6.9421 and height to 6.9441